# VSCode Autoindent After Equals Sign in Function for Scala

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code

Have not been able to get this to work similar to what I have in Intellij but trying to have vscode autoindent my line by 2 spaces when I start a function definition with an equals operator without any braces.

This does not autoindent:

```
  def myfunc(x: String): String = 
  x
```

This does autoindent:

```
  def myfunc(x: String): String = {
    x
  }
```

Comment: Things like "code context indentation" are features of IDEs as this needs that the "editor" understands the code. VsCode is an Editor and it is not capable of doing that. You can install "metals" to get ide like features for scala in VsCode.

Comment: Thank you. I should have mentioned that I'm already using metals. Is there a setting I can configure to get what I'm looking for?

Comment: try using scala-fmt

Comment: I'm not sure that's the solution. that project says it is deprecated in favor of using metals.

Comment: scala-fmt is an build tool integrated code formatter. Its totally different from metals. You are probably confusing it with something else.